# structure within structure declared in a file not able to access inner structure

Tags: c, linux, struct

I have created a file msgbuf.h which is as follows:

```
//msgbuf.h
typedef struct msgbuf1
{
    long    mtype;
    M1      *m;
} message_buf;

typedef struct msgclient
{
    int msglen;
    int msgtype;
    char cp[100];
}M1;
```

And a program as check.c. Below prog is giving error that there is no M1. Why is it so? What mistake am I doing? 
I think the contents of file "msgbuf.h" should get copied in the prog check.c and the program should run fine. Please let me know this.

```
//check.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"msgbuf.h"

int main()
{
    message_buf *sbuf;
    sbuf=malloc(sizeof(sbuf));
    sbuf->m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
    sbuf->m->msglen=10;
    printf("\n%d",sbuf->m->msglen);
    printf("\n %d",sizeof(sbuf->m));
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: should be `sbuf=malloc(sizeof(*sbuf));`

Comment: FYI - same thing could be achieved with forward declaration (`typedef struct M1 M1`) before first struct, and then defining `struct M1 { ... }` (without `typedef`) somewhere later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, declare `M1` before `message_buf`; .

```
typedef struct msgclient
{
    int msglen;
    int msgtype;
    char cp[100];
}M1;

typedef struct msgbuf1
{
    long    mtype;
    M1      *m;
} message_buf;
```

And read the  keltar's comments below the question too.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare M1 before using it:

```
//msgbuf.h
typedef struct msgclient
{
   int msglen;
   int msgtype;
   char cp[100];
}M1;

typedef struct msgbuf1
{
    long    mtype;
    M1      *m;
} message_buf;
```